# Multiple values from other fields in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have table, many rows, with column "landuse" (code numbers). I need column with text. How to do this in Field Calculator?

I mean this:

```
landuse   
200               
300               
1231              
300              
200         

new column:
wood
field
road
field
wood
```

**EDIT**

I have a solution...

```
CASE 
  WHEN "lu" IS 200 THEN 'Vacice virginska'
  WHEN "lu" IS 700 THEN 'korytnačkař'
  ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: You appear to have duplicate accounts, which is making editing a chore.  See [this Meta post on de-duplication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Answer (score 3):

Create a table with landuse_number and landuse_text, populate with unique values (one for each landuse), join this table with your shape data on landuse_number and then you can perform a field calculation to transfer the text values over permanently to a new field, or just work with them joined. Join tutorial can be found here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to add Field of type `Text`, and select a length of 20. You can name the new field "Class". Then, use `Field calculator` to update the "Class" field using the following formula:

```
CASE 
WHEN  "landuse" = 200 THEN 'wood' 
WHEN  "landuse" = 300 THEN 'field' 
WHEN  "landuse" = 1231 THEN 'road' 
END
```

Whether you use `is` or `=`, the expression is correct.